# how to get id from one table and insert it into another. postgresql

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I'm creating a favorite button and when the user likes a recipe I want to save the user id and the id of the recipe he liked. i am using knex.js and am still new to it and every code works except the part of getting the user id and recipe.

code for save the recipe:

```js
const { existsOrError } = app.api.validation

    const save = (req, res) => {
        const recipe = { ...req.body }
        if (req.params.id) recipe.id = req.params.id

        try {
            existsOrError(recipe.name, 'Name not informed')
            existsOrError(recipe.Ingredients, 'Ingredients not informed')
            existsOrError(recipe.time, 'Preparation time not informed')
            existsOrError(recipe.portion, 'portion not informed')
            existsOrError(recipe.preparation, 'Preparation not informed')

        } catch (msg) {
            res.status(400).send(msg)
        }

        if (recipe.id) {
            app.db('recipes')
                .update(recipe)
                .where({ id: recipe.id })
                .then(_ => res.status(204).send())
                .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err))
        } else {
            app.db('recipes')
                .insert(recipe)
                .then(_ => res.status(204).send())
                .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err))
        }
    }
```

code for save the user:

```js
const { existsOrError, notExistsOrError, equalsOrError } = app.api.validation

    const encryptPassword = password => {
        const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10)
        return bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt)
    }

    const save = async (req, res) => {
        const user = { ...req.body }
        if (req.params.id) user.id = req.params.id

        if (!req.originalUrl.startsWith('/users')) user.admin = false
        if (!req.user || !req.user.admin) user.admin = false

        try {
            existsOrError(user.name, 'Name not informed')
            existsOrError(user.email, 'Email not informed')
            existsOrError(user.birth, 'Date of birth not informed')
            existsOrError(user.password, 'Password not entered')
            existsOrError(user.confirmPassword, 'Invalid Password Confirmation')
            equalsOrError(user.password, user.confirmPassword,
                'Passwords do not match')

            const userFromDB = await app.db('users')
                .where({ email: user.email }).first()
            if (!user.id) {
                notExistsOrError(userFromDB, 'User already registered')
            }
        } catch (msg) {
            return res.status(400).send(msg)
        }

        user.password = encryptPassword(user.password)
        delete user.confirmPassword

        if (user.id) {
            app.db('users')
                .update(user)
                .where({ id: user.id })
                .whereNull('deletedAt')
                .then(_ => res.status(204).send())
                .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err))
        } else {
            app.db('users')
                .insert(user)
                .then(_ => res.status(204).send())
                .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err))
        }
    }
```

my attempt to get the id:

```js
const save = (req, res) => {

    const like = {
        id: req.body.id,
        userId: user.id,
        recipeId: recipe.id
    }

    app.db('likes')
        .insert(like)
        .then(_ => res.status(204).send())
        .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err))
    }

    return { save }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you should post the current recipe id in request body, and get user id from current session(get current logined user id), that depends on your web framework.